# how to automatically rename columns with math mode?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

Consider this simple example

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
```
## Slide with R Output
```{r , echo = FALSE ,warning = FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

  cars %>% 
    filter(dist < 5) %>%
     kable('latex',  booktabs = T, escape = F, col.names = c( "$\\alpha$"  , "$\\beta$" ) ) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"),
                full_width = T)

```
````

Now this correcly generates the following output

[image]

The issue is that the renaming in `col.names` is manual and very tedious when my dataframe has many columns.

I would like to be able to able to say " if you see this variable `dist` in the dataframe, then map it to $\alpha$. Otherwise leave as is.

How can this be done?
Note, I am rendering the file using `rmarkdown::render()`
Thanks!!

Comment: You could add `rename(\`$\\alpha$\` = dist)` before the kable call.

Comment: thanks but have you tried? does it work? there is an issue with the escape i think

Comment: I try to reproduce your document, but I can only compile it as html and not as pdf - don't know what's going on there.... But as an html it works... (that's why it's only a comment and not a solution)